# logger.info is not working in a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2
```

I've used logger.info successfully in the past. Today, I was trying to debug a model's action, and it's breaking my application. My code (in models/admin_ability.rb):

```
can :decline, Ticket do |ticket|
  if ticket.persisted?
    logger.info("File: #{__FILE__ } -- LINE: #{__LINE__ }")
    executor = ticket.executor
    ticket_profile = ticket.ticket_profile
    decliners = ticket.decliners
    suitable_companies = ''
    suitable_companies = ticket_profile.suitable_companies(decliners, ticket.customer, ticket.customer_info.zip, ticket.requested_date_start,
      false, false) if decliners.blank?
    suitable_companies.delete(ticket.executor)
    !(suitable_companies.compact).blank?
  end
end
```

Here's the error message:

```
undefined local variable or method `logger' for #<AdminAbility:0x007f8382bfd3f0>
Rails.root: /home/app

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/admin_ability.rb:40:in `block in initialize'
```

Line 40 is:

```
logger.info("File: #{__FILE__ } -- LINE: #{__LINE__ }")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `logger` on the `Rails` constant: `Rails.logger.info`

Comment: Your suggestion worked. I don't get it though. I've used it like a million times before, without any problems.

Comment: There's nothing adding the `logger` method in your cancan(can?) ability class file.  You've been able to use it elsewhere because various Rails classes supply the `logger` method for you, eg. [ActiveRecord::Base#logger](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-logger)